# Transforming n binary calls to one n-ary call in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

We have a helper function in our codebase to concatenate two (Windows) path strings:

```
CString AppendPath(CString const& part1, CString const& part2);
```

It is often used in this way:

```
const CString filePath = AppendPath(AppendPath(AppendPath(base, toplevel), sub1), filename);
```

This is rather acceptable, but it got me wondering if there is some possibility in C++ (or C++0x) to use a (template?) function to chain binary function calls together.

That is, **given a function `T f(T arg1, T arg2)` is it possible to write a function `T ncall(FnT fn, T arg1, T arg2, T arg3, ...)` that will call `f` like in my example above and return the result?**

```
// could roughly look like this with my example:
const CString filePath = ncall(&AppendPath, base, toplevel, sub1, filename);
```

*Please, this question is about the transformation and **not** about the best way to handle or concatenate path strings!*

---

*Edit:* Thanks to [deft_code](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28817/deft-code)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042034/transforming-n-binary-calls-to-one-n-ary-call-in-c/6065193#6065193) for providing the correct term for what I was asking for: [Fold (higher-order function)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29). <sub>(Note that I have settled on accepting [the answer of Matthieu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042034/transforming-n-binary-calls-to-one-n-ary-call-in-c/6042246#6042246) because his solution does not require C++0x.)</sub>

Comment: That sounds like a perfect use case for variadic templates. I can't remember the exact syntax though, so I'm making it a comment, instead of an answer. :) They're part of C++0x though (but not supported in VC2010)

Comment: @jalf: Made it an answer (not that I could remember the syntax either). Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Without C++0x, it's also possible to use chaining (I don't recommend overloading the comma operator, the syntax gets weird).

The syntax is somewhat different, but very close:

```
CString const Path = AppendPath(base)(toplevel)(sub1)(filename);
```

This is done simply by creating a temporary object that will perform the catenation through an overload of `operator()` and which will be implicitly convertible through `operator CString() const`.

```
class AppenderPath
{
public:
  AppenderPath(){}
  AppenderPath(CString s): _stream(s) {}

  AppenderPath& operator()(CString const& rhs) {
    _stream += "/";
    _stream += rhs;
    return *this;
  }

  operator CString() const { return _stream; }

private:
  CString _stream;
};
```

Then, you tweak `AppendPath` to return such an object:

```
AppenderPath AppendPath(CString s) { return AppenderPath(s); }
```

(Note, actually you could directly name it `AppendPath`)

Making it generic as per @Martin's suggestion:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename L, typename R>
class Fold1l
{
public:
  typedef void (*Func)(L&, R const&);

  Fold1l(Func func, L l): _func(func), _acc(l) {}

  Fold1l& operator()(R const& r) { (*_func)(_acc, r); return *this; }

  operator L() const { return _acc; }

private:
  Func _func;
  L _acc;
};

// U is just to foil argument deduction issue,
// since we only want U to be convertible into a R
template <typename R, typename L, typename U>
Fold1l<R,L> fold1l(void (*func)(L&, R const&), U l) {
  return Fold1l<R,L>(func, l);
}

void AppendPath(std::string& path, std::string const& next) {
  path += "/"; path += next;
}

int main() {
  std::string const path = fold1l(AppendPath, "base")("next");
  std::cout << path << std::endl;
}
```

Code validated on [ideone](http://ideone.com/6vAtq).

Comment: Woo, nifty. And by "you could directly name it AppendPath", you mean make the first call actually be a constructor call instead of a function call?

Comment: @Martinho: yes :) Note this syntax is very similar to the one used in Boost.Assign.

Comment: +1, but why `rhs` is not reference in `operator()(CString rhs)` ?

Comment: Hmmm ... the operator chaining approach sounds really nice! Should be doeable generically.

Comment: @Martin: yes, it's basically a `foldl1` call (in functional languages like `Haskell`) http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/foldl1_f.html

Comment: @Matthieu: Can you fix your code?  The class name is `AppenderPath` and operator() should return `*this`.

Comment: @quamrana: just noticed too :) People should get flogged when they don't compile before submitting *whistles*.

Comment: @Matthieu: That's why I compiled my sample before posting it :).  It worked first time!! Very unusual!!

Comment: @Martin: I've implemented the `fold1l` function. It requires slightly modifying the signature, for efficiency reasons, since we have mutable state in C++. Thanks for suggesting it :D

Comment: +1, I was wondering a couple of things (at completely different levels). On the higher level, I have used and found this pattern in different circumstances (create temporary helper in a function on which you can call different operations to complete a task, here `operator()`, in other circumstances `operator<<` [in place string builder]...) but I have never seen a name for this idiom, is there one?

Comment: On the completely opposite end of concerns, a *problem* (if you care to call it so) of the code above is that after calling `operator()` the expression becomes an lvalue..., which means that it is prone to misuse (bind a reference to it --even if it was `const`, that const reference would not extend the lifetime of the temporary...) and I was wondering if it actually made sense to endure the complexity of having a *move* (manually implemented in C++03) constructor so that each call to `operator()` would result in an rvalue at a reasonable cost... food for thought.

Comment: You should also add an rvalue reference overload.

Comment: @DeadMG: a function object would have meant polymorphism and lifetime issues, I preferred to stay clear of it for the purpose of what aimed at being a "simple" demo. As for rvalue... the code is meant for C++03, C++0x would completely change the way it written, with `std::function` and move semantics coming into play.

Comment: @David: the move semantics emulation would probably encounter the same issue that `auto_ptr` has. Sometimes I prefer to draw the line and rely on convention :) I firmly believe that the "bind to temporary" was a design mistake... easy with hindsight, I guess. And I do not know a name either, though I have used the construct several times already.

Answer (score 10):

In C++0x, you can use variadic templates. Something like this, perhaps:

```
template<typename... Args>
CString AppendAllPaths(CString const& part1, Args const&... partn)
{
    return AppendPath(part1, AppendAllPaths(partn...));
}

template<>
CString AppendAllPaths(CString const& part1, CString const& part2)
{
    return AppendPath(part1, part2);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Making [Martinho Fernandes' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042034/transforming-n-binary-calls-to-one-n-ary-call-in-c/6042121#6042121) more generic:

```
#define AUTO_RETURN(EXPR) -> decltype(EXPR) \
{ return EXPR; }

template<class F, class Arg1, class ...Args>
auto n_binary_to_1_nary(F func, Arg1 &&a, Args &&...rest)
AUTO_RETURN(func(std::forward<Arg1>(a),
                 n_binary_to_1_nary(func, std::forward<Args>(rest)...))))

template<class F, class Arg1, class Arg2>
auto n_binary_to_1_nary(F func, Arg1 &&a, Arg2 &&b)
AUTO_RETURN(func(std::forward<Arg1>(a), std::forward<Arg2>(b)))
```

Use:

```
n_binary_to_1_nary(&AppendPath, base, toplevel, sub1, filename)
```

---

However, AppendPath could simply be written in this style:

```
CString AppendPath(CString const &part1, CString const &part2);  // existing

template<class ...Args>
CString AppendPath(CString const &a, CString const &b, Args const &...rest) {
  return AppendPath(AppendPath(a, b), rest...);
}
```

You can, of course, add this overload and use it transparently in your code.

---

Or pass an initializer_list:

```
CString filePath = AppendPath({base, toplevel, sub1, filename});
```

Code:

```
template<class Iter>
CString AppendPath(Iter begin, Iter end) {
  CString result;
  if (begin == end) {
    assert(!"reporting an error (however you like) on an empty list of paths"
            " is probably a good idea");
  }
  else {
    result = *begin;
    while (++begin != end) {
      result = AppendPath(result, *begin);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

template<class C>
CString AppendPath(C const &c) {
  return AppendPath(c.begin(), c.end());
}
```

Notice the last AppendPath works with any STL-like container.  You can also add these overloads to your code and use them transparently.

Comment: You forgot to use rvalue references and `std::forward`.

Comment: I can't understand why the `AUTO_RETURN` functionality was not buitin in C++0x... :(   Even if sometimes it does not work (I don't remember the exact reason, something like when `this` appears in the expression)

Comment: @rafak: [Agreed.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/738001#738001)

Answer (score 2):

In this specific case of calling `AppendPath` I'd just write an overload of the function which has as its implementation your second line of code.

In the general case I'd write a series of templates:

```
template<typename T>
T ncall(T (*fn)(T const&,T const&), T const& p1, T const& p2, T const& p3){
    return fn(fn(p1, p2), p3);
}
template<typename T>
T ncall(T (*fn)(T const&,T const&), T const& p1, T const& p2, T const& p3, T const& p4){
    return ncall(fn, fn(p1, p2), p3, p4);
}
template<typename T>
T ncall(T (*fn)(T const&,T const&), T const& p1, T const& p2, T const& p3, T const& p4, T const& p5){
    return ncall(fn, fn(p1, p2), p3, p4, p5);
}
```

Which I'm sure could be easily generated automatically.

Answer (score 1):

> Given a function T f(T arg1, T arg2) is it possible to write a function T ncall(FnT fn, T arg1, T arg2, T arg3, ...) that will call f like in my example above and return the result?

Everyone is soo close to a general foldl implementation.  Here is an even more general solution than the question asked.  It accepts functions like `T f(T arg1, T arg2)` as well as `T1 f(T2 arg1, T3 arg2)`.  Also I named the function *foldl* in homage to its functional roots.

```
#define AUTO_RETURN( EXPR ) -> decltype( EXPR ) \
{ return EXPR; }

template< typename BinaryFunc, typename First, typename Second >
auto foldl( BinaryFunc&& func, First&& first, Second&& second )
AUTO_RETURN( func( std::forward<First>(first), std::forward<Second>(second) ) )

template<typename BinaryFunc,typename First, typename Second, typename... Rest >
auto foldl( BinaryFunc&& func, First&& first, Second&& second, Rest&&... rest )
AUTO_RETURN(
   foldl(
      std::forward<BinaryFunc>(func),
      std::forward<decltype( func(first,second) )>(
         func( std::forward<First>(first), std::forward<Second>(second) )),
      std::forward<Rest>(rest)... )
   )
```

An example of how this would solve your problem:

```
auto path = foldl( &AppendPath, base, toplevel, sub1, filename );
```

Another example showing off all of foldl's strength:

```
struct stream
{
   template< typename T >
   std::ostream& operator()( std::ostream& out, T&& t ) const
   {
      out << std::forward<T>(t);
      return out;
   }
};

struct Foo
{
   Foo( void ) = default;
   Foo( const Foo& ) = delete;
   Foo& operator=( const Foo& ) = delete;
};

std::ostream& operator << ( std::ostream& out, const Foo& )
{
   out << "foo";
   return out;
}

int main()
{
   foldl( stream(), std::cout, 1, ' ', 1.1, ' ', Foo{}, '\n' );
}
```

See the output / code in action at [ideone](http://ideone.com/D0qDq).